# Invisible redirection to IIS site

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, redirect

I developped and set up an IIS website for a customer, and I would like my customer to be able to make an invisible redirection to this site, so that users will see only my customer's subdomain and never mine.

For example:
IIS site: server.mycompany.com/site
Client subdomain: example.customer.com

I would like to make an invisible redirection, from example.customer.com to server.mycompany.com/site (without using iframes).

Customer subdomain is making a DNS redirection to our site, that works well but now I would like to hide our URL from site users. I've looked into IIS rewrite module, but I didn't manage to make it work. I'm not even sure this is the right approach, it seemed to me that URL rewrite only allowed to redirect inside the same domain.

From what I've read, what I'm looking for is possible but I can't figure out if it requires an action in IIS or on my customer's domain ? I'm a little lost.

Comment: You don't want a redirection. Redirection always implies that after the redirection the new URL is visible. You only need to set a CNAME or an A record for your customers domain to your server.

Comment: Thanks for this comment ! I've made a few tests and now and I understand a little more how it works. But DNS records only allow to point to an IP address, and I would like to point to a subdomain site: server.mycompany.com/site. My server has only one IP address and several sites. Does that mean I need one IP per site ?

Comment: No. You only have to configure IIS to use the /site subdirectory as a document root for the subdomain. I'm not familiar with IIS though.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing What you need is to configure IIS as reverse proxy.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I added a CNAME entry for each of my subdomains, and that's working fine. Now I would like to hide the /site part of the URL, I will try to use URL rewrite for that. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any rewrites, and especially no reverse proxy settings.

Create a CNAME for `subdomain.example.com` that points to your domain, or an A record that points toward the IP of your server. Which one doesn't really matter.

Then, add a new Site in your IIS.

Use `subdomain.example.com` as the site name and point the `Physical path` to your `site` directory:

[image]

That's all.

Comment: I made that work on my local IIS instance, but on my server IIS always displays the default IIS page when I access the site directly, even if the physical path is my site directory. Anyway, I much appreciate your help, thank you Gerald :)