# IIS Url rewrite rule to hide application name

Tags: iis, rewrite

I have 2 sites in my IIS server, each is binded to a subdomain and contains one app named myapp. I would like to write a rewrite rule hide the name of the app (myapp) and show only the subdomain I use to the user.

Practically, it means that
subdomain1/myapp/anything should be displayed subdomain1/anything to the user.

I've tried many rewrite rules, on every level : server, site and app, nothing works. All I'm getting are 404 errors. It seems that whatever I try, the myapp prefix will always be added. What am I missing ?

Comment: Go over the tutorials provided by Microsoft to really understand how to write rules, and then learn FRT on how to troubleshoot, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: You don't need any rewrites. I explained my comment in [your first question](https://serverfault.com/questions/990790/invisible-redirection-to-iis-site/990973#990973) in more detail in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to move my application up at site level, so that the name of the subfolder would not appear in the URL. It sounds quite obvious now but my first attempts to do that where unsuccessful, so I thought it wasn't possible.

As Gerald said, all is explained in his answer to my other question :
[Invisible redirection to IIS site](https://serverfault.com/questions/990790/invisible-redirection-to-iis-site/990973#990973)